# AWS Kinesis Analytics - Apache custom access log schema issue

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, logging, schema, amazon-kinesis

Im trying to use kinesis analytics on top of the Apache access log. Im using custom format which has county code (using geoip module).

But its not detecting the schema properly.

Log format:

```
LogFormat "%{GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE}e %a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

Kinesis Schema detection:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I found the solution.

Generally Kinesis is pretty mature to the schema from some standard format. Even in the agent conf file, if we mention the `logformat:COMBINEDAPACHELOG` then it'll detect the schema.

But I used custom log format. So we need to manually edit the schema and add missing field. Also `space` is not a good choice for delimiter. So I have modified the delimiter as `pipe` in the apache log format.

Then manually edited the schema and mentioned the pipe as a delimiter. After that, Im getting the exact formatted data.